# Android Fragmentation AlertDialog Problem?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest, android-fragments

When I run a code for the alertDialog on an Emulator with Android 2.2 it works like its supposed to and everything however, when I attempt to do the same on my Samsung Captivate which also runs on Android 2.2 it gives a transparent black cover over the application layout just like in the emulator except it fails to show the actual Dialog none of the edittext and other elements are focusable just like in a regular dialog environment however, again, the actual Dialog is missing.  I don't understand what to do as both run on the same Operating System.  Below is the code (it is located in the onCreate() method of my Activity):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Please rate me on the Android Market!")
   .setCancelable(true)
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: You could start by showing us the code your using to create the dialog. There are lots of ways to do it and I don't think anyone can help you without info.

Comment: Just now added the code, Sorry about that

Comment: What does "this" refer to in this case, is it activity or are you in a subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try debugging the application on your device, and connect it through the USB cable if you are not already doing so. This has never happened to me, and I do not see it as a bug or a common occurrence. If you are not showing the complete code for the dialog, it could have something to do with internet(or other permissions running before and after this code). I would suggest you check:

1) Permissions

2)Storage Problems

3) Confirm the compatibility of the application and your device once more.

Hope this helps.